# calculate min distance of each shop's location sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, latitude-longitude, geo

I have a table which contains X,Y Coordinates of each shop. I want to find min distance with each other. I mean nearest shop.

For Ex: (Desired Output)

```
Shop_ID      Nearest_Shop_ID 
Shop_1       Shop_5
Shop_2       Shop_8
Shop_3       Shop_4


Select SHOP_ID, Longtitude, Latitude From PARTNER_ADDRESSES
group by SHOP_ID, Longtitude, Latitude;
```

This is my shop coordinates table;

```
SHOP_ID     LONGTITUDE  LATITUDE
38599       32.815282   39.882793
38613       25.965545   42.166315
38682       31.845157   37.419859
38686       34.027568   38.370871
```

I have a formula which could calculate distance between two location (with using latitude and longtitude). This is the formula;

```
(NVL(6387.7,0) * ACOS((sin(NVL(Latitude1,0) / 57.29577951) * SIN(NVL(Latitude2,0) / 57.29577951)) +
        (COS(NVL(Latitude1,0) / 57.29577951) * COS(NVL(Latitude2,0) / 57.29577951) *
         COS(NVL(Longtitude2,0) / 57.29577951 - NVL(Longtitude1,0)/ 57.29577951))))

Latitude1  : Shop 1's Latitude value
Longtitude1: Shop 1's Longtitude value

Latitude2  : Shop 2's Latitude value
Longtitude2: Shop 2's Longtitude value
```

Is it possible to write this kind of sql which will calculate each shop distances and list min distance value for each shop?

Comment: How large is your table?  How important is performance?

Comment: There are 5000 shops in my table. Performance is important for us. Thanks @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `self join` and `analytical function`.

```
Select s1, s2 from
(Select a1.shop_id as s1, a2.shop_id as s2,
Row_number() 
over (partition by a1.shop_id
  Order by <your_formula>) as rn
From partner_adresses a1
Join partner_adresses a2
On (a1.shop_id <> a2.shop_id))
Where rn = 1;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do each shop vs each shop using cross join, like

```
select <distance formula> from shops as ashops cross join shops as bshops
```

and from there, using a nested SQL you can select the one from minimal distance for each of the shops

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a `cross join`, then a `row_number`:

```
with distance1 as (
select
pa1.SHOP_ID as shop_id1, pa1.Longtitude longitude_1, pa1.Latitude latitude_1,
pa2.SHOP_ID as shop_id2, pa2.Longtitude longitude_2, pa2.Latitude latitude_2,
<your_distance_formula> as Distance
from PARTNER_ADDRESSES pa1
cross join PARTNER_ADDRESSES pa2
where pa1.SHOP_ID <> pa2.SHOP_ID -- remove record where shops are the same
)

select *
from (
select *,
row_number() over (partition by shop_id1 order by Distance) rn_distance
from distance1
) 
where rn_distance = 1
```